# Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[@class="btn btn-primary"]' is not a valid XPath expression using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, syntax-error

I try to write a script in Python which allows me to put an Item into Cart on an Onlineshop.
I am not a Pro in programming so be kind to me :).

Here is the HTML:

```html
<button
  class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn"
  data-attr-name="Product Detail Page - Level 1"
  data-attr-value="Add to Shopping Cart"
  data-attr-proddata='{
    "productName":"WLAN-Lautsprecher-Set MR 50",
    "productID":"1010950",
    "brand":"Blaupunkt",
    "ownedBrand":"",
    "priceWithTax":179.0,
    "quantity":1}'
  type="submit"
  disabled="disabled"
>
  <i class="icon-hd icon-ic-caddy-o"></i>
  <span class="hidden-xs">In den Warenkorb</span>
</button>
```

Here is the snippet of my code that causes the error:

```py
...
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)
driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn"][@type, "submit"]).click()
...
```

The error is:

```py
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn"][@type, "submit"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: headless chrome=86.0.4240.197)
```

If i delete the "'" then a Syntaxerror occures:

```
 File "/home/pi/login.py", line 29
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn"][@type, "submit"]).click()
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It is only a Hobby-Project, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

P.S.: I run the code on a Raspberry Pi 4. with selenium with Chrome in headless-mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close enough. As the error points out:

```
    driver.find_element_by_xpath(//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn"][@type, "submit"]).click()
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The python interpreter complains of *`invalid syntax`* as you have missed the quotes for the *value* of the [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath).

---

### Solution

Effectively your line of code will be:

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn" and @type="submit"]').click()
```

Alternative:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn' and @type='submit']").click()
```

Considering [`find_element_by_*`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/_modules/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.html#WebDriver.find_element_by_xpath) commands being deprecated and using `find_element()` instead:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn' and @type='submit']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try using

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-add-to-cart").click()
```

*ps.I'm a noob and I've never used xpath before so*

Answer (score 0):

This is the valid xpath use 'and' to add multiple attributes to expression

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block js-add-to-cart js-enable-btn" and @type="submit"]')
```

## also enclose locator in quotes